# How to use the native client toolchain?

Tags: google-nativeclient

I had compiled the native client toolchain in my own Linux OS.

In native client source code I found that using `make test_hello_world_nexe` can build a hello world program and run it. To my understanding it must be using the downloaded toolchain instead of your own toolchain to compile, as it doesn't need to supply location of your toolchain.

So how do I use the toolchain that compiled by myself, to build my own application to a .nexe?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Had finally figured out how to use the toolchain. Here is an example on Windows from [Building Native Client Modules](https://developers.google.com/native-client/devguide/devcycle/building#compiling), if you are using NaCl SDK:

```
<NACL_SDK_ROOT>/toolchain/win_x86_newlib/bin/i686-nacl-gcc hello_world.c -o hello_world_x86_32.nexe -m32 -g -O0 -lppapi
```

`<NACL_SDK_ROOT>` represents the path to the top-level directory of the bundle you are using, e.g., `<location-where-you-installed-the-SDK>/pepper_23`.

If you are not using NaCl SDK, then you might need to compile and link ppapi lib manually. In Native Client source code, there is a tool to help automate all of above:

```
python native_client/build/build_nexe.py -t "/path/to/toolchain/" --arch x86-32 --build newlib_nexe --root .. --name "hello.nexe" --objdir . "--compile_flags=-m32 -mtls-use-call <more-flags...>" "--link_flags=-m32 -O3 " "--source-list=hello.list"
```

By this you can get a `hello.nexe` compiled. Then another tool can be used to check its output:

```
python native_client/run.py -m32 hello.nexe
```

Note that if you are using `Glibc` to dynamically link the program, then you might need to supply library path, e.g.

```
python native_client/run.py -L/path/to/lib/ -m32 hello.nexe
```